# Is there a term for an intentional, pleasing juxtaposition of elements?

Tags: single-word-requests

**I made a paper plane out of airplane documents.**

There's something satisfying about combinations like this, but I've never been able to locate a word that captures the concept:

- It has the same feeling as irony, but there's no contradiction;
- It's like serendipity, but with no luck or chance as it's an intentional combination;
- It's like coincidence or synchronicity, but intentional instead of accidental

Is there a single word for this? The closest I can describe is "a satisfying juxtaposition", which doesn't have the right feel to me.

Comment: Sounds *poetic*.

Comment: "I make my living singing love songs, that I made up 'cause I love songs" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FSzFl1VA_AE

Comment: ChatGPT suggests harmony or consonance, which are also good candidates. Over the years, *poetic* has definitely grown on me. Feel free to add that as an answer if you want some internet points @YosefBaskin